# Files in fstab mounted CIFS folders are not available automatically

Tags: mount, fstab

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10, and I've mounted some NAS folders using /etc/fstab. My problem is, that after rebooting Linux, applications such as Crashplan and VirtualBox (shared folders) see all mounted folders as if they were empty. I have to manually enter each folder once using e.g. Nautilus to make files visible.

Options in fstab are: iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,user

How to make these folders be accessible automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the following instructions from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) worked for me on Lubuntu 15.10

> **Unprotected network folder won't automount**
>
> I've had a situation where an unprotected network folder wouldn't automount during bootup, but after manually entering "sudo mount -a" was mounted correctly. I solved this by replacing the "guest" option by "username=guest,password=".
>
> //servername/sharename  /media/windowsshare  smbfs  username=guest,password=,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode  0  0
>
> **Mount password protected network folders**
>
> The quickest way to auto-mounting a password-protected share is to edit /etc/fstab (with root privileges), to add this line:
>
> //servername/sharename  /media/windowsshare  cifs  username=msusername,password=mspassword,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0

Additional to this I used the following option to assure auto mount works:

> _netdev
>
> //servername/sharename /media/cloud cifs **_netdev**,uid=1000,gid=1000,dir_mode=0700,file_mode=0600,nounix,forceuid,forcegid,credentials=/home/myuser/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0